# I can't make anaconda work on windows by importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, command-prompt, geany

I am new to Python and am trying to use anaconda to do some data analysis. I am using Python 3.6.2 along with the geany text editor.

First, I'm trying to execute a file call panda.py which only contains `import pandas as dp`.

When I configure geany with a working directory of `C:\Users\Anaconda3\python`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panda.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as dp
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .numerictypes import object_
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 962, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 958, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

The same error also occurs when I enter the following at the command prompt:

`C:\Users\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\Documents\python_work\panda.py`

However, if I execute `C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\python.exe` and then enter `import pandas as dp` in the REPL, it appears to load without error.

Any idea how I can fix this so I can use anaconda with geany?

[SOLVED] John below ask if I had a file called numbers.py in my directory which made me realize I named an exercise I previously did as numbers.py. Once I removed it, the error went away (I tested it further by adding a file with the name again and the error returned).

I'm new to the stack over flow community. Let me know if there's anything else I need to do to close out this question.

Also thanks to chb for the edits to my original question the format looks much easier to read.

Comment: Do you have a file in your working directory named `numbers.py` or `numbers.pyc`?

Comment: How are you configuring your working directory in Geany?

Comment: I do have a file named numbers.py in my folder where I'm storing my program files. I'll try to delete it and see if that fixes it.

Comment: John Gordan, thank you so much! It's been so frustrating. Once I deleted numbers.py it worked. I even added it back to see if it was the issue and the error returned. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate everyone's suggestions and time as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: python on windows is not something I know about

You know that `C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\python.exe` when run standalone knows how to import pandas, so your setup is fine - you have everything installed that you need, and in the correct locations.

Given that, you can look at two issues: gearny setup, and general setup. I noticed that python and pandas is installed under `C:\Users\Anaconda3`, while your program is under `C:\Users\Documents\python_work`, and we also have `C:\Users\David` - could it be permissions issues?

Comment: I tried to remove all references to David for privacy's sake. I must have missed one. They are all in the same location.

Comment: I don't know why it won't import pandas from a .py file is my big problem now. Seems really inefficient to paste all my code into python as opposed to using a editor (and I would think I should be able to some how).